# sed to match and replace 2 consecutive lines?

Tags: sed

I want to match 2 consecutive lines then replace it. For example this pattern:
`[0-9]\(.*\)\n[0-9]\(.*\)`
so basically both lines are started with a number.
Then replace it:
`\2\n\1`
Means swap the line content and ditch the leading number.
example file 1:

```
 adfa
adaf
dfd
1 1a
2 2b
3 3d
adfa
sdfa
4 4a
5 5b
6 6d
7 7k
```

example file 2:

```
 adfa
adaf
dfd
aaa
1 1a
2 2b
3 3d
sdfa
4 4a
5 5b
6 6d
7 7k
```

Many answers online suggest using `N;` or `1!N;` but This will not work.
The reason is `N;` will start from 1st line, then read every 2 lines, `1!N;` will start from 2nd line, then read every 2 lines. But what I want is to read each line and its next line to match. If N and N+1 lines matched we replace on this 2 lines, then move to the N+3 and N+4 line to match, If no match, we move to N+4 and N+5 ...
The expected result will be following for both example files:

```
2b
1a
5b
4a
7k
6d
```

The failed commands:

```
sed 'N;s%[0-9]\(.*\)\n[0-9]\(.*\)%\2\n\1%;t;d' test0.txt
 3d
 2b
 5b
 4a
 7k
 6d

sed 'N;s%[0-9]\(.*\)\n[0-9]\(.*\)%\2\n\1%;t;d' test1.txt
 2b
 1a
 5b
 4a
 7k
 6d


sed '1!N;s%[0-9]\(.*\)\n[0-9]\(.*\)%\2\n\1%;t;d' test0.txt
 2b
 1a
 6d
 5b
7 7k
sed '1!N;s%[0-9]\(.*\)\n[0-9]\(.*\)%\2\n\1%;t;d' test.txt
 3d
 2b
 6d
 5b
7 7k
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `D` instead of `d`, i.e. delete first line of pattern-space and repeat-if-not-empty, then it works, e.g.:

```
sed -nE 'N; s/^[0-9] (.*)\n[0-9] (.*)/\2\n\1/; ta; D; :a; p' infile
```

Or even cleaner as suggested by *@potong*:

```
sed 'N;/^[0-9] \(.*\)\n[0-9] \(.*\)/!D;s//\2\n\1/' infile
```

Output:

```
2b
1a
5b
4a
7k
6d
```

Comment: An alternative might be: `sed 'N;/^[0-9] \(.*\)\n[0-9] \(.*\)/!D;s//\2\n\1/' file`

Comment: @potong: I like it

Answer (score 1):

A imperfect way to achieve it

```
sed -nr '/^[0-9]/{N;s/.*([0-9][[:alpha:]]).*([0-9][[:alpha:]])/\2\n\1/p}'
```

1. We use `N` only if the line start by a number.
2. Then we could use regular expression to do as we need.

> This regexp is designed by your example file, and should be adjusted if the format of your file changed.

Comment: An alternative since the OP is not concerned with the values the second column `sed -nr '/^[0-9] /{N;s/^. (.*)\n[0-9] (.*)/\2\n\1/p}' file`